# Find command to return absolute path

Tags: unix, directory, find, csh, absolute-path

I'm using find command a lot on unix (csh).

Is it possible that the result will be full/absolute path and will start from the directory where I'm starting the search

> for example when running command from `/project/Test/v0.15/test/frontend`, the
>   results are:

```
./core/serdes_complex/frontend/lib/lib_behave.f
./core/serdes_complex/frontend/lib/test_srd_compile.f
```

But i would like to get

```
/project/Test/v0.15/test/frontend/core/serdes_complex/frontend/lib/lib_behave.f
/project/Test/v0.15/test/frontend/core/serdes_complex/frontend/lib/test_srd_compile.f
```

Comment: How are you using find command? I guess searching directly from `/` instead of your current directory would solve your problem!

Comment: I think this might answer your question: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125779/how-do-i-get-absolute-path-from-using-find-unix-command

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try searching from `$cwd`:

```
find $cwd -name \*.f
```

Comment: Or just use the full path e.g. `find /home/user/path/ -iname ...`

Answer (score 13):

You should use the command [realpath](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/realpath.1.html) to resolve the path :

```
find . -name "*.f" -exec realpath {} \;
```

Comment: This isn't the approach I'd usually take, but it's an interesting one :-)

Answer (score 8):

I got it to work using `$PWD`:

`find $PWD -name \*.f`